# Rest API send websocket message as well as response entity

Tags: spring, spring-boot, rest, websocket

I'm using spring boot and I was wondering if I can create a REST API that also sends a message to a websocket channel? so anyone subscribed to it can get it.  Since it's a rest api, there would also be a response entity when it's done as well.  If so, can i see an example of how that would work? i've been googling everywhere.

Answer (score 1):

Good starting points to build a Spring Boot application with Websocket support are

- [WebSockets](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/reference/html/web.html#websocket) chapter in the official Spring documentation
- [WebSocket Security](https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/current/reference/html5/#websocket) chapter in the Spring security documentation
- Baeldung post [Intro to Security and WebSockets](https://www.baeldung.com/spring-security-websockets)

To determine connected users you can use `SimpUserRegistry` bean and to send messages to them you can use `SimpMessagingTemplate`, for example:

```java
@RestController
public class ApiController {

    private final SimpMessagingTemplate template;
    private final SimpUserRegistry userRegistry;

    public ApiController(SimpMessagingTemplate template, SimpUserRegistry userRegistry) {
        this.template = template;
        this.userRegistry = userRegistry;
    }

    @PostMapping("/api/users/{username}/send")
    public ResponseEntity<?> sendMessage(@RequestBody Message message, @PathVariable String username) {
        Set<SimpUser> users = userRegistry.getUsers();
        if (users.stream().anyMatch(simpUser -> simpUser.getName().equals(username))) {
            template.convertAndSendToUser(username, "/messages", message);
            return ResponseEntity.noContent().build();
        } else {
            return ResponseEntity.notFound().build();
        }
    }
}
```

You can check my minimal example of working [Websockets demo application](https://github.com/Cepr0/sb-websocket-user-demo).

Comment: thanks, i'll give this a try, and see if that works.  It seems like the key is using simpMessagingTemplate to convert and send.  I tried htat before with no luck but i'll try this.  Thanks Cepr0